# How do I set a Range variable, using two other Range variables?

Tags: vba, excel

In my Excel macro, I have two Range Datatype variables

- `RangeStrt` with value say `Range("A1")`
- `RangeEnd`  with value say `Range("C10")`

I need a third Range variable `DataRng` which will store the range from start to end (i.e `Range("A1:C10")`).

Is there anyway I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The technical aspect on how to set the `Range` was given in the answer above by @user3598756

I also suggest (in case you are not already familiar) to fully qualify your `Range`s, with the relevant worksheet where these ranges are located.

So, you should add `With Worksheets("YourSheetName")` before setting-up the ranges, and inside the `With` statement, qualify your `Range` by adding a `.` before.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub DefineCombinedRange()

Dim RangeStrt As Range
Dim RangeEnd  As Range
Dim DataRng  As Range

' add With statement to fully qualify your Ranges
With Worksheets("Sheet1") '<-- modify "Sheet1" with your sheet's name (where you have your ranges)
    Set RangeStrt = .Range("A1")
    Set RangeEnd = .Range("C10")

    Set DataRng = Range(RangeStrt, RangeEnd) '<-- setting the 3rd range, using the first 2 Ranges

    ' the line below is for debug
    Debug.Print DataRng.Address
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
Set dataRng = Range(RangeStrt, RangeEnd)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition of the @user3598756 answer (which is OK), you can also use this:

```
Range(Cells(1,1), Cells(10,3)).Select
```

Personally I prefear this one because you can use more easily some index inside the Cells formula.